# Seeing Breakdown of GitHub Actions Usage In GitHub Organization

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I manage a GitHub Organization, which has hundreds of repos in it. We have a share amount of GitHub Actions minutes, which runs out very fast. Based on [this document](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-billing-and-payments-on-github/viewing-your-github-actions-usage), I can see the total minutes used but I need to find a way to see which repos or which actions consumed the most minutes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download a CSV usage report from that same area of the GitHub interface (Settings > Billing and Plans > Usage this Month):

[image: GitHub Settings showing usage button]

It's only for the current period and it's a bit of a pain to work with, but the data's certainly all there.

Having said that, I had the same problem so I built an extension for GitHub's `gh` client to pull out the information in a slightly less painful way:
https://github.com/codiform/gh-actions-usage

This is based on an earlier GitHub extension that was built using bash before they added support for binary extensions, which does roughly the same thing but is slower (because it's built using a bash script that invokes the `gh` client repeatedly):
https://github.com/geoffreywiseman/gh-actuse